# How do you select a vertex loop without a scroll wheel or middle mouse button?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices, selection-tools

I am having trouble with selecting an edge loop in blender 2.82. I do not have current access to a scroll wheel or a middle mouse button! Please help. I'm stuck on a big project with a tight deadline.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). *Edge loops* are selected with Alt+LMB. No scroll wheel needed.

Comment: Need to check 'Emulate 3 buttons mouse' in the input tab of the preferences to make Alt+LMB work.

Comment: Suggestion get a low cost USB mouse with a scroll wheel by any means. USB mouse devices are common place and available online, from your professional colleagues, drug stores, discount stores , junk drawers, and Walmart. I am not endorsing any particular store or assuming any geographical location. The cost of a laptop is hundreds of times the cost of a mouse. [Big projects and Tight Deadlines] have budgets for such low cost items. Translated to American dollars I have a usable USB mouse for $3. You need the tools for your future projects. Which comes first ? The laptop or the mouse?  .